# How can I pass a textbox value from one aspx page to another aspx page in VB.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to pass a textbox value from one aspx page to another aspx page. I have tried - Previous page property and Application variable. I do not want to use cookies for this textbox. I have tried the below code in page 2 and it throws me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 If Not IsNothing(Request.Cookies("IMF")("UserID")) Then

                lblUserID.Text = (Request.Cookies("IMF")("UserID").ToString())

                Dim txt As TextBox
                txt = CType(Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("txtUsername"), TextBox)

                If Not IsNothing(txt) Then
                    lblUserName.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(txt.Text)
                Else
                    lblUserName.Text = "[Name Not available]"
                End If

            End If
```

Comment: better approach, by my opinion, storing value into `session` and on load another page pull that value from `session` and put in desired `textbox`... for example : **page1.aspx** (codebehind, right before redirect to another page) `Session.Add("myvalue",TextBox1.Text)` and on load **page2.aspx** : `Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load : TextBox2.Text = Session("myvalue"):End Sub` ...

Comment: Another way: pass the value as a `QueryString` parameter.

Comment: im not 100% sure with Asp.net, however with a standard desktop application, it would be something like this `TextBox1.Text = Form1.TextBox1.text`

Comment: Passing trough `QueryString` too, like @ConnorsFan wrote, but, since You pass value from `TextBox` it would be good using `UrlEncode/Decode`.